# GitLab, manual job with dependency

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

My pipeline has 3 stages: *Test*, *Prepare* and *Publish*.

- *Test*, is executed for any commit on any branch
- *Prepare*, is executed on **develop** and **master**
- *Publish*, reuse artifacts from *Prepare* and is executed on *develop** and **master**

I have added on manual stage *"Manual publish"* to manually publish any successful commit from anything else than **develop** and **master**. However that  stage require the artifacts from *Prepare*. I have used `needs` to run *Prepare* but that one is executed after *Test* either if we don't trigger the *"Manual publish"*, this is a waste of time and resources.

Can we attach/import/merge an existing job in another one ?

I have tried to import the *Prepare* job in *Manual publish* but without success:

```
build-and-publish-manually:     
  <<: *prepare-docker
  <<: *build-and-publish
  except:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $DEVELOP_BRANCH 
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $MASTER_BRANCH
  when: manual
```

Each job should be executed on different runner; `prepare-artifact` is executed inside a Docker runner while `build-and-publish` require a Shell runner.

Comment: From my experience for manual jobs we just run manually whole pipeline and required manual steps are executed only then. Is it really such a waste of resources? I mean how often are you using this manual executions and how much does it consume that you need to execute only one step? For more advanced pipelines we use Jenkins, it is easy to configure it to take artifacts from certain build number (e.g. as parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make the first job manual and the next one "needing" it.

I have added a *Manual Prepare* job triggered manually and the *Publish* job is configured to `needs` the *Manual Prepare*. So that he is executed only once the *Manual Prepare* is done.

```
# ...

prepare-docker-manually:
  <<: *prepare-docker
  when: manual

build-and-publish-manually:     
  <<: *build-and-publish
  except:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $DEVELOP_BRANCH 
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $MASTER_BRANCH
```

[image]